# Get content of current document C# Word Addin

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-addins

I would like to get the content of the currently opened Word document.
At the moment my code saves the document, closes it and then reads the file content. (Then converts to utf8 base64 for REST file upload)
Is it possible to get the documents content without closing it?
Could I also get the content as e.g. xml, because at the moment I can't open the document again after base64 decode. (The document is defect, i think its converted wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution:

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.get_XML()));
```